# Order of evaluation of java expression

Tags: java

So I have to arraylists which represent integers for example `num1 = <-1,4,5>` would represent -145 and `num2= <2,3,6>` would represent 236.

```
ArrayList<Integer> num1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,9));
ArrayList<Integer> num2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(-5,5));
final int sign = num1.get(0) < 0 ^ num2.get(0) < 0 ? -1 : 1;
```

So sign is supposed to determine the sign that would occur from multiplying num1 with num2 (`-145*236` would be a negative number). So comparison operators are non associative so this should be an equivalent expression:

```
sign = (num1.get(0) < 0 ^ num2.get(0)) && (0 ^ num2.get(0) < 0) ? -1:1;
```

Whats confusing me is why is `num2.get(0)` being XOR'ed with 0 because that does not alter `num2.get(0)` at all.

Also lets say `num2.get(0) = -2` and `num1.get(0) = -3` then if we evaluated for sign we'd get sign=-1. Because `(-3< 0 ^ -2) AND (0 ^ -2 < 0)? -1:1;` evaluates to -1.

But this would be wrong -3*-2 should be a positive number. So what am I missing because I know this code is correct (it's from a textbook).

Comment: This isn't correct java `AND` is not java. `0 ^ num2.get(0) < 0` is nonsense. 
 `<` binds more tightly than `^`, so this is `xor`ing an `int` with a `boolean`. You're also right that xor'ing an `int` with zero does nothing. Trust me. There are lot's a errors in textbooks.

Comment: If all you want is the sign, you might consider `Integer.signum( num1.get(0) * num2.get(0) )`.

Comment: These two aren't equivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
num1.get(0) < 0 ^ num2.get(0) < 0 ? -1 : 1
```

is evaluated as

```
((num1.get(0) < 0) ^ (num2.get(0) < 0)) ? -1 : 1
```

This is determined by operator precedence. Comparison operators being non-associative has nothing to do with it whatsoever.

> Whats confusing me is why is num2.get(0) being XOR'ed with 0

It isn't.